# Use of "proceed with something"

Tags: verbs, american-english, synonyms, north-american-english

Is it normal to use "proceed with something" in American English speaking? Isn't it a little formal? Is there a better alternative? Can we use "do something" instead?

Comment: Less formal: "go ahead with"

Comment: When I place an order with someone and I'm asked if it's okay to "proceed with the order", I'd say "please go ahead with the order". When you say "do the order", it can mean either "process the order" or "place the order (again, for some reason)".

Comment: What does "proceed with" mean?

Comment: It means "go ahead with".

Comment: it means " continue", or it can mean start and finish?

Comment: It means to resume at some point to finish.

Comment: Yes, it's normal, in formal settings.  For example, if the parties in a legal proceeding are in mediation and are considering canceling the hearing, they might throw in the towel and let the administrative law judge know that the mediation failed and that they will be proceeding to hearing.

Comment: In any form of English *proceed with something* is normal and will be understood by all (native) parties.
It is not relevantly *formal*.
There is no significantly *better* alternative.
You can use *do something* instead and it will not change the meaning except that, for instance, *proceed with the purchase* will and *do the purchase* will not be correct.

Answer (score 1):

If I proceed to build a house, I start work on it. I undertake the building of it. So, in this sense, “proceed “ means “begin” or “start.”